# Cast an entire vector

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism, reinterpret-cast, static-cast

Is it possible to cast a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>>` to an `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SpecializedObject>>` where `SpecializedObject` inherits `Object`, without building a new array (or iterate through the vector)?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: no, really.

Comment: @skypjack even if the data stored is guaranteed to be a std::shared_ptr<SpecializedObject>?

Comment: @Talesseed: Indeed. You still have two basically unrelated element types.

Comment: If you can guarantee the type of the things in the vector, why not create a vector of that type in the first place?

Comment: @NeilButterworth because of vectors of vectors

Comment: Hardly an explanation. I suspect the basic problem is with your design.

Comment: Well, yes, it's an explanation. A vector of variant-vectors may make more sense tho.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I need to class objects by type (vector containing vectors containing objects of a specific inherited type)

Comment: Consider making a view type that looks at the vector and casts on the fly?  The view is templated on the type to want to cast *to*. The 'operator[](size_t) returns static_cast<_ViewTp>(this->_M_vec[i])'.

Comment: @emsr from what I understood it can't be done

Comment: @emsr Ok I understood. I just wanted to cast the entire vector for optimization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer:

`std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>>` and `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SpecializedObject>>` are completely different and unrelated beasts and you cannot cast from one type to the other one.
You must iterate through the vector and create a new one from that.

Hint: you can still use `static_pointer_cast` to cast the pointers while iterating (if you know what you are doing, of course).

Comment: Ok, it's a shame though.